# What 's usage of syntax-case in this form in Racket/Scheme

Tags: scheme, pattern-matching, racket

I am confused by the documentation about the usage syntax-case, but what can `f` possibly mean?

```
(define-syntax (check stx)
   (syntax-case stx ()
       [(f (x y))
        #'(list 'second: f x y)]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is broken in a fairly subtle way.

To begin with,

```
(define-syntax (check stx)
   (syntax-case stx ()
       [(f (x y))
        #'(list 'second: f x y)]))

(check (3 4))
```

Yields an error: check: bad syntax in: check

The problem, though, is the *use* of 'f' that appears in the expansion. To see this, try taking it out:

```
(define-syntax (check stx)
   (syntax-case stx ()
       [(f (x y))
        #'(list 'second: 1234 x y)]))

(check (3 4))
```

This evaluates fine, producing '(second: 1234 3 4)

So, why does the first one fail? The problem is that in your first example,

```
(check (3 4))
```

expands into

```
(list 'second check 3 4)
```

The problem with this, though, is that the 'check' in the expansion is another use of the 'check' macro, and must therefore be *further* expanded, and this second expansion does not have the right shape.

To see this, you can try expanding your program using the macro stepper. Run the macro stepper, use the pull-down menu to select "Standard" macro hiding, click on the "End-->" button, and then go back one step.

The normal convention is to use the underscore "_" as a "don't care" symbol to match against the name of the macro in the pattern, like this:

```
(define-syntax (check stx)
   (syntax-case stx ()
       [(_ (x y))
        #'(list 'second: 1234 x y)]))

(check (3 4))
```

Out of curiosity: where does this code come from?

Comment: I am learning syntax in racket, the code is for testing. 
So if I replace `f` in the first example with `(f (x y))`, the code is correct in syntax, though ends up an infinite recursion. Thx.

Comment: John: You should have mentioned the macro stepper!